# in Drupal 6, how do i set permissions so that a given role may assign roles to other users, but not access the permissions page?

Tags: php, security, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'd like to allow "staff member" users to assign roles to other users, but not to change the permissions associated with any particular role.

ideally I'd like the master permissions table to only be accessible to user #1.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? or do i have to find/write a module to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [Role Delegation](http://drupal.org/project/role_delegation) fits the bill.

Comment: yeah, that looked like a good idea. But it doesn't seem to play nice with Role Expire http://drupal.org/project/role_expire

Comment: Does http://drupal.org/node/831232 describe the problem you had with Role Expire with regards to Role Delegation? There's a patch in that issue for review.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up throwing:

```
<?php
  $items['admin/user/permissions']['access callback'] = FALSE;
?>
```

into a custom module, but Role Delegation + Role Expire *should* have done what i wanted :/